# magento on Zend Server (Win7) installation error

Tags: installation, zend-server, magento

I try to install magento for the first time.

- I've created the database with the
  name "project"
- in my C:\Zend\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf I
  added on the end:

  > ```
  > <Directory "C:\Zend\Apche2\htdocs\project">
  >     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  >     AllowOverride All
  >     Order allow,deny
  >     Allow from all
  > </Directory>
  > ```
- in my ZendServer/Server Setup/Extensions: PDO_MySQL, simplexml, mcrypt, hash, GD, DOM, iconv, curl, SOAP are on
- in C:\Zend\ZendServer\etc\php.ini I set:

> ```
> safe_mode = Off ;<-- was set to off
> ...
> memory_limit = 512M; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
> ```

After step "Configuration" of magento installation (with Use Web Server (Apache) Rewrites enabled) I get:

- **Internal Server Error**

My database is full of tables (that schould be ok)

My Zend Server shows:

```
27-Oct 06:55    6    Severe Slow Request Execution (Absolute)    http://localhost/project/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/    Critical Open
27-Oct 06:55    4    Fatal PHP Error    C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php        Critical    Open
27-Oct 06:55    5    Slow Function Execution    curl_exec        Warning    Open
27-Oct 06:55    5    Slow Request Execution (Absolute)    http://localhost/project/index.php/install/wizard/configPost/
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: perhaps it is because you wrote "Apche2" instead of "Apache2" on the configuration you added on the httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

While installing Magento; the page will redirect recursively and will show the default browser page. While checking the Apache access log the below error shows
    "GET /magento/index.php/install/ HTTP/1.1" 302 92706
This can be fixed using the Apache configuration. Open the file httpd.conf. Change the below lines:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
<FilesMatch>
```

to

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Reference http://wp.me/p8AtY-gc

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo?

`<Directory "C:\Zend\Apche2\htdocs\project">`

`<Directory "C:\Zend\ApAche2\htdocs\project">`

Comment: Here yes, on the server no.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have access to the Internet?  curl_exec is trying to request material from the web and is timing out...

Comment: How to check this? I've ZendServer-php-5.3.3-5.0.3-Windows_x86 on win7 x64.